# CSR Generation from local computer

Tags: ssl, openssl

How do l run the csr generation command on cmd.exe

openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout www_mydomain_com.key -out www_mydomain_com.csr -subj "/C=BB/ST=CCC/L=DDD/O=EEE./OU=IT/CN=mydomain.com"

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd.exe, go to your OpenSSL installation folder, let's say "C:\OpenSSL", then go to "bin" and place your command.

Comment: Thank u, l managed to do it by referencing the openssl.exe on cmd.exe before the command after reinstalling openssl